# proguard dead code analysis gives false positive for private field

Tags: java, proguard, dead-code

Given the following class

```
package com.example;

public class ProguardConstantFieldUsageDemo {

    private static final String CONSTANT_FIELD = "I'm not dead!";

    public String publicMethodUsingConstant() {
        return CONSTANT_FIELD + "I agree, you are not dead.";
    }

}
```

and a configuration requesting dead code analysis

```
...
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontpreverify
-printusage result
... + keep statement to keep the public method
```

proguard (version 6.2.2) claims the constant field is dead code:

```
com.example.ProguardConstantFieldUsageDemo:
    private static final java.lang.String CONSTANT_FIELD
```

Is this a bug in proguard or a feature (caused by inlining by javac or something) or is there a way to configure proguard not to give this false positive?

Comment: Maybe it removes the field, and even merely the entire constant string `"I'm not dead!I agree, you are not dead."` is kept in the constant pool of the class.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yes, that's what I'm also speculating with my "caused by inlining by javac". If that's the case and proguard cannot do anything about it, this is a blocker that pretty much makes the dead code analysis useless. There are just too many false positives in a normal codebase.

Comment: Oh crap, it seems to be the case:

    javap -l -c -constants -cp THEJAR THECLASS

outputs:

    ...
    0: ldc           #3                  // String I'm not dead!I agree
    ...

Comment: There is something to say to remove CONSTANT_FIELD as field, maybe keep it a local variable does not trigger a code checker. One does not have to like a prescribed styles, if only one can live with them.

Comment: @JoopEggen Private constants are often very useful, so I don't think refactoring them away is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by javac inlining the constant:

```
javap -l -c -constants -cp THEJAR com.example.ProguardConstantFieldUsageDemo
```

outputs

```
...
0: ldc #3 // String I'm not dead!I agree
...
```

So the constant really doesn't exist in the bytecode. The same seems to happen to non-static and non-final fields, too.

The solution is to configure proguard to keep all private fields:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
  private <fields>;
}
```

This will also suppress warnings about real dead fields, but it's not a big problem, because other static analyzers are able to find them, since they are private.